# Arduino - Stop execution of code definitly

Tags: arduino

I've got a big problem with my new Arduino. I made a big mistake, and now I can't anymore connect to my arduino. Is there any possibility to recover the Arduino, or to **stop** the execution of code definitly?

Here my code:

```
void setup () {
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop () {
  Serial.write("Hello World!");
}
```

My problem is, that this code is executed so immediatly after booting the Arduino, and I can't upload something different to the Arduino...

Please help me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok thanks, I found the solution yesterday:

1. Unplug the USB cable
2. Hold down Reset
3. Plug in the USB cable
4. Upload Code from IDE
5. Release the Reset Button after seeing the compile done message
6. AND NOW IT DOES IT'S JOB GOOD AGAIN.

Comment: Feel free to select this as the answer to your own question.

Answer (score 2):

I have just solved this type of problem on my Arduino Mega.
I had uploaded the program given in Example →communication →MIDI and the Arduino went on transmitting data to serial port and **I could't upload any new program**.

What I did to solve:

1. My Computer(Right Click) →**Properties**
2. **Device Manager**
3. Found Arduino in Port List and open properties of it. (only available when it is connected to PC)
4. **Port Setting →Advanced**
5. Uncheked the ***Use FIFO Buffers***
6. Then uploaded

   - I think the continuous receiving of data for computer can full the FIFO Buffers
   - I wish it works for all Arduino
   - I just tested on Arduino Mega 2560 ADK and worked

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [bootloader code](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/blob/master/hardware/arduino/bootloaders/atmega8/ATmegaBOOT.c). It seems that sending '0' to the Arduino as early as possible might hold it in bootloader mode.

Try sending "0000000000" to the Arduino, followed quickly by uploading your code.

Failing that, use another Arduino to program yours via the ISP pins.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload) troubleshooting guide. The Auto-reset section may help.

Comment: just giving a link does not qualify as an answer. A good answer should explain a solution and give links to source for more detailed information and attribution. This is currently a comment, please expand it and make it great!